# Check which button was clicked in ckeditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have added two button on canvas using

**Button1**

```
editor.ui.addButton('button1', {
    label : editor.lang.button1,
    command : COMMAND_NAME
});
```

**Button2**

```
editor.ui.addButton('button2', {
    label : editor.lang.button2,
    command : COMMAND_NAME
});
```

And here is the command definition

```
editor.addCommand(COMMAND_NAME, { 
    exec: function(editorInstance) {
        // some task
    } 
});
```

Both the button will call the same command. Is there any way in command definition that which button called the command?

Comment: Don't you have a `event` parameter in our function call ?

Comment: Why don't you use different `command`'s for the different buttons?

Comment: yes! I can use the different commands. but is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at the documentation for [addButton](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui-method-addButton) and [addCommand](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addCommand) I don't think that there's a way to determine between the calling buttons in the `exec` callback. The [command definition](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.commandDefinition) has an optional `data` parameter but [from the source](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/button/plugin.js) I can't see that this is provided by the button's click function.

But of course you could use different `command`'s for different buttons.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr4xp421/1/)

```
editor.ui.addButton('button1', {
    label : 'Button1',
    command : 'mycommand1'
});
editor.ui.addButton('button2', {
    label : 'Button2',
    command : 'mycommand2'
});
editor.addCommand('mycommand1', { 
    exec: function(editorInstance) {
        console.log('button1/command1');
    } 
});
editor.addCommand('mycommand2', { 
    exec: function(editorInstance) {
        console.log('button2/command2');
    } 
});
```

And to use the same function for different buttons you could use:

```
function mySpecialFunction(button) {
}
...
editor.addCommand('mycommand1', { 
    exec: function(editorInstance) {
        mySpecialFunction('button1');
    } 
});
editor.addCommand('mycommand2', { 
    exec: function(editorInstance) {
        mySpecialFunction('button2');
    } 
});
```

Comment: if i use the same command then which button initiated command execution?

Comment: @SunilGarg There's only one parameter for the `exec` function (editorInstance) - so: no. That's what the `command` parameter is for.

Comment: @SunilGarg It is not completely true that the `exec` function has only one parameter. There's an optional `data` parameter but this does not seem to be provided by the button's click event. See my updated answer.